# Add attribute to Model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've read a few guides on adding an attribute to a Model in rails, but none seem to specify the Model you're affecting in the Migration.

I'd like to add an `image_url` property to our `coffees` model, but the migration examples I've seen don't specify a model. What would I need to do to get this working correctly?

Answer (score 5):

Well the migration api is pretty clear:

```
add_column :table, :column_name, :column_type
```

Example:

```
add_column :coffees, :image_url, :string
```

Answer (score 1):

you create a new migration file to add `image_url` in `Coffee` models retaled table.

if you write

```
 rails g migration AddImageUrlToCoffees image_url:string
```

then a migration file will be generated like

```
class AddImageUrlToCoffees < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :coffees, :image_url, :string
  end
end
```

or

```
class AddImageUrlToCoffees < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :coffees, :image_url, :string
  end
  def down
    remove_column :coffees, :image_url, :string
  end
end
```

when you run `rake db:migrate` then it will add one more column `image_url` in coffees table and it  can be access from model Coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in the console

```
rails generate migration AddImageUrlToCoffees image_url:string
```

it will generate for you with

```
class AddImageUrlToCoffees < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :coffees, :image_url, :string
  end
end
```